# Weird Selenium Click Behaviour C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am automating a website using Selenium.
I have made a Console Application using C# in Visual Studio.
In that I execute a click on an element. The click should open a new window.
But, it doesn't.
If I close the console window to stop the project, the desired window which should have opened on the click, opens up now.

Earlier, this used to work all fine. But this problem has occurred recently. There has been no change in the code.

Browser is Internet Explorer.

Anyone knows what could have caused such a behavior and how to fix it ?

Comment: Your code would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot share the code as it is not meant to be. But it runs on a different PC normally. I haven't set any internetexplorersettings  except that unexpectedaltert one to to allow.

Comment: If you can't share your own code, can you make up a simple, minimal example that exhibits the same problem, and post that?

Comment: Thank You !! I figured it out. The problem was with the browser and not with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do the 2 pc have different screen sizes? If the element is not shown on the page, the 1st click will *bring you to the element, but not click it*.